# Why are my Mango leaves crinkled?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves

This is my first time on here but I have been growing a small mango sprout since last month and it has grown well. The leaves that are growing however are a little deformed and crinkled but when I checked the roots they were health and green with small white tips. As for the soil composition it is a mix of gravel and plain soil with orchard mix at the top. I ran out of the plain soil so I decided to create medium layers.[image: it is curled crinkled and the rest of the leaves are curled as well.]

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to give it FULL sun. It looks like you are keeping it near a windowsill, but in my experience, baby mango plants need at least 6+ hours of full sun per day.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the pH of your soil & water mangoes like it's slightly acidic so between 5.5 and 6.0

Comment: You could improve your answer by citing a reference for that.